# PriorityQueue algorithm searching for the smallest k value is returning incorrect result

Tags: java, algorithm, priority-queue

I am trying to find the smallest kth value for an array.  I used a priorityQueue data structure to remove  values that are greater than k, but I am returning an incorrect result. My code is below:

```
public class Main2 {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    
    public int smallestK(int[] arr, int k) {
        
        for(int num : arr) {
            maxHeap.add(num);
            if(maxHeap.size() > k) {
                maxHeap.poll();
            }
        }
        return maxHeap.peek(); 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 12, 3, 5, 7, 4, 19, 26 };
        
        Main2 smallest = new Main2();
        int result = smallest.smallestK(arr, 3); //should return 5, but returns 12
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

How can I fix the algorithm to return the correct result?

Comment: @JanezKuhar there’s no need to completely fill the queue before pruning it, as you’re suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not create a Max Heap, but a Min Heap. To create a Max Heap you need to pass a comparator to the PriorityQueue constructor:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I am just learning Java, so I thought it was a Max Heap, by the way does runing the Collections.reverseOrder() change the complexity of this, or is it the same complexity as the Min Heap?

Comment: The complexity remains the same. One comparison takes constant time.

Comment: @trincot Just curious about what will be the time complexity of inserting elements in the priority queue, as we are building and doing heapify as well?

Comment: Have a look at the time complexity table on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants). You may assume that Java's PriorityQueue is implemented as a binary heap. If you have further questions, don't hesitate to post a new question (unless it has been asked before).